# Uploading single image into a CNN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I tried uploading a single image for prediction into a CNN model using the following code and I'm getting an error as:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 54, 50, 3), found shape=(None, 54, 50, 4)
How can I solve this?

```
from PIL import Image

def test_img(file):
    img = Image.open(file)
    ih = ImageHandler([img]).resize((54,50)).normalize()
    
    ogmodel = models.load_model('../models/best_original.h5')
    
    result = (ogmodel.predict(ih.images) > 0.5).astype("int32")
    
    print(result)

test_img("../bees/test_imgs/beex.png")
```

Comment: You supply RGBA image with 4 channels, but seems the model expects 3 channels: RGB. You may discard the 4th channel, e.g. by `img = numpy.array(img)[..., :3]`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Thanks so much! I was able to solve the error.